# Django: DateTimeField, how to make require only date.

Tags: django, django-models

I want to have DateTimeField(Not separate DateField and TimeField) but i want only date to be required or only time to have default value. Is it possible and if yes .. how :)

Comment: You mean that you want the user to provide only the date, but have it stored as a `datetime` with a preset time? And you want this to work in the admin, with a date picker widget?

Comment: I want something like this: If user don't want to provide time, default time should be 12:00 for example. But if user want to set time, time should be choosen time